# If statement returning NaN

Tags: javascript, acrobat

Am totaling several form fields where users put in hours of the day. However, some users would like to put an "X" if they were not present that day. So I tried several different if statements to try to get the calculation to recognize "X" as a zero when running the calculation but still show an X in the form field. I went as far as creating a hidden form field and default its value to zero and that is the last thing I tried.

Here is my formula (please keep in mind, I will have to use this for each day of the week but I just was playing around with the first one)

```
var v1 += getField("mon1_str."+row).value;
if(v1 == "X") event.value = "defaultvalue";
else event.value = "";
```

The first line of script gets my value no problem. Its the second line and third line where i am not having any luck. It should be noted that no errors are coming up in the console window. "defaultvalue" is the name of my hidden form field to grab a value from.

Answer (score 1):

The `+` tries to convert the string to a number. But `'x'` can't be converted to a number, so it results in `NaN`.

```js
console.log(+'X');
```

Try saving the plain value, checking if it's `'X'`, and then converting it to a number later.

Comment: Thank you. So remove the "+" from the getField script and leave the same if statement for X that I have. But if I want to change a numeric value to recognize as a number, how would that script read? I will start toying with some script while I wait for your response. If I get it in the meantime, i will repost. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: Like I said, just convert it to a number later if you need to parse it as a number, preferably with `Number()`. eg `const numberValue = Number(getField("mon1_str."+row).value)`